A question about homomorphism from union of groups, when viewed as a structure.
Suppose we have a finite set of Abelian groups $\{(G_i,+_i): i\in I\}$. Additionally, for each $G_i$, we have a $n_i$ s.t. $(G_i,+_i)\cong ((\mathbb{Z}_2)^{n_i},+)$, as groups. It might be the case that the intersection between them is non-empty.
Now we can view the operation $+$, and each operation $+_i$, as a 3 place relation. Hence we can define the structure $G=(\bigcup_{i\in I}G_i, \bigcup_{i\in I}+_i)$.  My question is, whether there is a non-trivial relational homomorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$. If it the case that the pairwise intersection of $G_i$s are empty, then such a map exists, but I am interested in the case when there the intersections between them are non-empty.
Can anyone help me with this question? If the above doesn't hold, can we maybe get a counter example?  Thank you very much in advance!

What is a (structural) homomorphism?

Also, is it of concern to you that $\bigcup_{i \in I} +i$ need not be a well-defined binary operation on the set $\bigcup{i \in I} G_i$? For example, perhaps there exists $x,y \in G_i \cap G_j$ such that $x +_i y \ne x +_j y$?

By structural homomorphism I mean a relational homomorphism, I will update my question. And good point about the non well-defined nature of the operation, I assume that in the case that there is non-empty intersection, the binary function is still well-defined.

Please edit your question to explain precisely the condition on intersections. Do you require $G_i\cap G_j$ to be a subgroup of both $G_i$ and $G_j$ when it is non-empty? Also, how did the question come up? What's the motivation?
